# Tensorflow's quantization for RNN and LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

In the guide for Quantization Aware Training, I noticed that RNN and LSTM were listed in the roadmap for "future support". Does anyone know if it is supported now?

Is using Post-Training Quantization also possible for quantizing RNN and LSTM? I don't see much information or discussion about it so I wonder if it is possible now or if it is still in development.

Thank you.

I am currently trying to implement a speech enhancement model in 8-bit integer based on DTLN (https://github.com/breizhn/DTLN). However, when I tried to infer the quantized model without any audio/ empty array, it adds a weird waveform on top of the result: [A constant signal every 125 Hz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqlvG.png). I have checked other places in the code and there is no problem, just boils down to the quantization process with RNN/LSTM.